# How to move Homestead/VM from running on the C drive to the F drive?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I currently have Homestead running on Windows 7 from the home directory i.e. `C:/Users/username`

My `C` Drive is running low on space and has not raids. But, I have another drive labeled "F" which has raid 0 to help keeping my data/files safer in case of an HD crash and it also has more storage space.

I would like to move my Homestead and projects to the F drive.

Here is what I have done so far.

From the command line i executed the following commands

```
f:
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
mkdir Projects
```

Then I edited the init.sh file located on `F:/Homestead` from the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

homesteadRoot=~/.homestead

mkdir -p "$homesteadRoot"

cp -i src/stubs/Homestead.yaml "$homesteadRoot/Homestead.yaml"
cp -i src/stubs/after.sh "$homesteadRoot/after.sh"
cp -i src/stubs/aliases "$homesteadRoot/aliases"

echo "Homestead initialized!"
```

to the code below so that the files are executed on the F drive instead of the home drive

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

homesteadRoot=/f/.homestead

mkdir -p "$homesteadRoot"

cp -i src/stubs/Homestead.yaml "$homesteadRoot/Homestead.yaml"
cp -i src/stubs/after.sh "$homesteadRoot/after.sh"
cp -i src/stubs/aliases "$homesteadRoot/aliases"

echo "Homestead initialized!"
```

Then using Git Bash I executed the following command from F:\Homestead

```
bash init.sh
```

Then I manually created the `.ssh` folder on the F drive and then created my rsa key like this

```
mkdir .ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
```

Finally, I updated my Homestead.yaml to look like this

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 5120
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: /f/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /f/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /f/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects
      type: "nfs"

sites:
    - map: dev.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Projects/Project1/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

However I keep getting `No input file specified.` when I go to 192.168.10.10:8000

Then when I try to SSH into the server like this

```
vagrant SSH
```

I find a different path than what I expected "or defined in my Homestead.yaml" this is what I see

```
cd /home/vagrant/Projects/Projects1/Project1
```

Hence: please note the the folder naming in the box

I see file different that the files located on my laptop

```
F:\Projects\Project1\public
```

What am I doing wrong? what should I do to correctly run Homestead on my machine on the F drive not on the users home drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Windows paths in places you should be using Linux paths.

Homestead uses a virtual machine running Linux, and Linux won't need to know or care that you're now running Homestead on your F: drive instead of your C: drive.

The way Homestead works is a folder is mapped from your Windows operating system to the Linux operating system. Then from inside the Homestead Linux machine, it doesn't have to know or care where the files sit (C: or F:).

Everywhere you've put `/f/` is incorrect; this doesn't exist on either Windows or Linux.

First, you need to undo any changes you've made to files ending in `.sh`. These files run in Linux, and so will not need to be modified for this move to F:.

> init.sh
>   homesteadRoot=/f/.homestead

Revert to

```
homesteadRoot=~/.homestead
```

Next, I believe the only change that will be required is in your Homestead.yaml:

```
folders:
    - map: F:/Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

Answer (score 0):

I had successfully moved my Project folder from C: drive to D: drive. I had to change few homestead files as following.

Change the following line in **Vagrantfile** in Homestead directory

```
-confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.join(Dir.home, ".homestead"))
```

To

```
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

If you are working on Mac or Linux, do following changes in **init.sh** file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cp -i src/stubs/Homestead.yaml Homestead.yaml
cp -i src/stubs/after.sh after.sh
cp -i src/stubs/aliases aliases

echo "Homestead initialized!"
```

On Windows **init.bat** file contains following changes

```
@echo off

copy /-y src\stubs\Homestead.yaml Homestead.yaml
copy /-y src\stubs\after.sh after.sh
copy /-y src\stubs\aliases aliases

echo Homestead initialized!
```

Finally you have to give your 'Projects' folder path in 'map' key in **Headstead.yaml** file. On my pc, **Projects** folder exists inside Homestead directory and **map** path has given as follows in Headstead.yaml.

```
folders:
    - map: D:/vagrant/Homestead/Projects
       to: /home/vagrant/Projects
```

Run following command in Git Bash to reload vagrant box.

```
bash init.sh
vagrant reload --provision
```